# Running thread groups sequentially in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, threadgroup

I am trying to run a script with two thread groups each for multiple users. script looks like

Test Plan
Thread group 1 (10 users, ramp up period 5 sec and loop count 1)
Samplers
Thread group 2 (10 users, ramp up period 5 sec and loop count 1, thread startup delay 3 sec)
samplers.

both thread groups share some parameters. So I am using Inter thread communication plugin. My requirement is that for first user I want to run thread group1 and then run thread group2 . then start threadgroup1 for second user. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, an "user" belongs to Thread Group, they don't share any context.

User 1 of Thread Group 1 and user 2 of Thread Group 2 are different beasts.

Normally you should not be passing anything between thread groups, if you need - most probably the test is badly designed and you need to move Samplers under a single Thread Group.

- If thread groups "share" some parameters - take a look at [User Defined Variables](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables)
- If thread groups "share" some test steps - take a look at [Test Fragments](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment) and [Module Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Module_Controller)

Comment: Actually I am implementing script for web socket connection. I need two connections to open. according to documentation of the plugin I am using, it is not possible. So I moved second connection to a different thread group. When i checked logs that was working. So I can not move samplers into one thread group :(